# Text going outside of page margins in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, margins

I'm writing a book on my life as a farmer but seem to be having an issue with text going outside of the document margins? Does anyone know why this is happening?

[Link to my document](http://www.filedropper.com/johndaviesmanuscript29october)

Comment: Can you at least host the image somewhere so we can embed it? I have no interest in downloading an image / malware

Comment: Are you using 2007 or 2010 or openoffice, you should be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is page indenting.

Ill show you a few examples of why this is happening.

[image]

**When you do first line indent:**

[image]

**Hanging Indent:**

[image]

**Left Indent:**

[image]

**Go to all of your paragraphs and realign them back to 0 on the ruler. Then adjust your indents to your liking.**

**Don't forget about fixing your margins**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to mass-do the change without going through all 140+ pages?

Comment: no, there isn't unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a single paragraph in a long Word document. I just copied sentence segments from the offending paragraph into the text section that was properly formatted, then when all had been copied into the correct margin setup I erased the original text in the offending section and cut what was left of the original paragraph, now blank.